# angular routing not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack, angular-routing

Below is my app.js file

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('farmApp',['ngRoute','toastr','firebase','employeeModule']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
    {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {
                templateUrl : 'App/views/index.ejs'
            })
            .when('/employees',
                {
                templateUrl : 'App/views/employees/employees.ejs'
            })
             .when('/newemployee',
                 {
            templateUrl : 'App/views/employees/newEmployee.ejs'
             })
            .when('/employees/edit/:id',
            {
                templateUrl : 'App/views/employees/editEmployee.ejs'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true,
            requireBase: false});

    });
})();
```

Down here is my first page, i am trying to route to an edit page whose route is already defined in my app.js file above. I see the changes in my URL in my web browser.But the edit page does not render. All my other routes work fine, so i'm not sure where the issue is.

```
<div ng-app="employeeModule">

  <div ng-controller="employeeCtrl">

    <div class="row" ng-init="initList()">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title">Employees</h4>
            <hr>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" href="/newemployee">New Employee <i class="ti-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="single in employees">
                <td>{{single.name}}</td>
                <td>{{single.salary}}</td>
                <th>{{single.phone}}</th>
                <th>{{single.address}}</th>
                <th>{{single.position}}</th>
                <td><a href="/employees/edit/{{single.$id}}"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a></td>
                <td><i class="ti-trash" ng-click="remove(single)"></i></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `#`? `<a href="#/employees/edit/{{single.$id}}">`

Comment: Are you sure `{{single.$id}}` is a proper value ?

Comment: @AndrewDonovan yes i'm sure. i'm using firebase for data, that puts the appropriate ID in the url